# Multiplication of Multiplicative Subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Definition: Let $R$ be a commutative unitary ring. A *multiplicative subset* $S\subset R$ is one that satisfies: (a) $1\in S$, and (b) $\forall s,t,\in S: s\cdot t \in S$.

My question is, how do you multiply two such multiplicative subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$, i.e. what is $S_1\cdot S_2$? Is the notion of multiplication here the same as when multiplying two ideals of a ring, or is it different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is $S_1S_2=\{s_1s_2\mid s_1\in S_1,s_2\in S_2\}$, and it follows that $S_1\subseteq S_1S_2$ and $S_2\subseteq S_1S_2$. It is different from the multiplication of the ideals, $IJ=\{\sum^n_ix_iy_i\mid x_i\in I,y_i\in J,n\in\mathbb N\}$. For ideals you need to make finite sums in order to get a new ideal. For multiplicative sets it is straight.

Comment: What if we want the multiplication to be bent? :P